# no attribute 'set_keras_submodules'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

getting:

> AttributeError: module 'keras_applications' has no attribute
>   'set_keras_submodules'

in:

```
keras_applications.set_keras_submodules(backend, layers, models, utils)
```

solutions of this issue
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25062
don't solve the error

on:

- python 3.7.3
- tensorflow 1.14.0
- keras 2.2.4
- keras_applications 1.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downgrade keras_applications to 1.0.7 solve the problem for me